# Sklearn SVM coefficient attribute - how to get class name?

Tags: python, numpy, svm, libsvm

When I get the coefficients for my multiclass SVM, I can't seem to find a way to retrieve what class the weights are for. They're sorted in some order. Is there a way to retrieve which class goes with which index in the coefficient 2D array?

Comment: As far I know the coefficients (`coef_`) are just the weights that form the separating hyper plane. One weight per feature, I don't see where the classes come into play, here. Are you perhaps looking for the support vectors, instead?

Comment: @kazemakase hmmm, it seems like when I look at the documentation for the coef parameter that it indeed returns a 2D array for feature weights per class.

Comment: You are right. There are different weights for each combination of classes in the multi-class case. You did not mention you were doing multi-class, though :)

Comment: @kazemakase ah edited, thanks! So my question is how it's ordered, ie what class does index n correspond to

Comment: I am working on an answer, but it's tricky :)

Comment: I asnwered a question a few days ago that goes in the same line... not sure if it is entirely related but you can take a look to my answer where I talk about `dual_coef_` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022270/which-support-vectors-returned-in-multiclass-svm-sklearn/35025497#35025497

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the order of classes from the `classes_` attribute. I think they are usually in ascending order as numpy.unique would sort them, but as far I know this is not documented.

If you do multi-class classification scikit-learn employs a one-vs-one scheme. This means you get one separate classifier (or one set of weights) for each combination of classes. If `C` is the number of classes there is a total of `C * (C-1) / 2` combinations.
Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any information on how these comibantions are ordered, either. However, from looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/base.py#L28) it seems that they are ordered as follows:

```
0-1, 0-2, 0-3, ... 0-c,
     1-2, 1-3, ... 1-c,
          2-3, ... 2-c,
                .
                .
                .
```

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

x = np.random.randn(40, 7)  # 7 features, 40 samples
y = ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'] * 10  # four classes
svc = SVC(kernel='linear').fit(x, y)

print(svc.classes_)  # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print(svc.coef_.shape)  # (6, 7)
```

The shape of `svc.coef_` shows that there are 6 sets of weights. These correspond to the following class label pairs:
AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD

**Note:** *This answer is based on observation and source code inspection, not on actual documentation. Take it with a grain of salt :)*